# Render different update action based on params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my controller I need to call different `update.js` based of existence of a parameter.
How to do it correctly?

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js do
      if params[:ble].present?
        'one/update.js'
      else
        'two/update.js'
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: it looks good, is it giving error?

Comment: it doesnt touch the 'one/update.js', i put the debugger there

Comment: does it *touch* without `if..else..`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're just forgetting to explicitly call `render`, but you also need to specify `layout: false`

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js do
    if params[:ble].present?
      render 'one/update.js', layout: false
    else
      render 'two/update.js', layout: false
    end
  end
end
```